# Нужно подсчитать и вывести количество строк у двух значений

Tags: php, mysql

Например дано:

- Таблица (id, orel, reshka) - (айди игры, кому выпало "орел", кому
  выпало "решка")

  Имеет примерно такой вид  (

  1, Вова, Олег

  2, Вова, Олег

  3, Олег,  Дима

  4, Дима, Вова

  5, Олег, Вова

  6, Артем, Олег

  )

Необходимо:

- Подсчитать количество выпавших значений "Решка" и количество значений
  "Орел" у игрока "Олег" в последних трех его играх.
- А также присвоить количество очков за результат, например:

  Орел = 2 очка, Решка = 1 очко.

  Если у игрока "Олег" из трех результатов выпало 2 "орла" и 1 "решка",
  то соответственно ему будет засчитано 5 очков

**Обновление**

Затрудняюсь в выборе последних 3-х игр и выводе результата этих игр.

Например запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE `orel`='Олег' OR `reshka`='Олег' LIMIT 3;
```

Выводит все игры указанного игрока, в которых он участвовал. Но как в этом запросе выбрать только последние 3 игры  и как "забиндить" результат этих игр для меня трудновато. Даже не знаю в какую сторону копать.

Comment: а что у вас вызвало затруднение? выпавшие "орел/решка" - это количество записей с таким именем, а отсюда уже и очки не сложно получить

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это выполнения задания за автора

Comment: для начала определитесь с тем что считать "последние три игры" - у вас можете дата игры есть, может вы по id хотите определять, может еще что-то. Затем определяем результаты игр, в вашем случае будет проще (т.к. всего 3 игры) просто выбрать игры, где играл Олег, а потом на php подсчитать результат сравнивая значения полей

Comment: если Вы не знаете как получить последние три записи, то так и задайте вопрос, в текущей Вашей формулировке это офтопик, и небольшая подсказка как бы делал это я: `Select * from table order by id desc limit 3` т.е. сортируем коллекцию и получаем ограниченное количество записей, если что меня поправят более опытные коллеги

Comment: @Bald56rus работа за автора не может являться причиной закрытия сама по себе - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0?cb=1

Comment: @PashaPash согласен не удачно выбрал тему закрытия. Но подробности появились позднее. Здесь наверно было бы более уместно другая тема закрытия. И я пытался спасти вопрос посоветовав Автору его изменить на что то более подробное

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT sum(if(`orel`='Олег',1,0)) r_orel,
       sum(if(`reshka`='Олег',1,0)) r_reshka
  FROM table 
 WHERE `orel`='Олег' OR `reshka`='Олег' 
 ORDER BY id desc /* тут должна быть условия сортировки последных игр */
 LIMIT 3;
```